# Regex (C#) - how to match variable names that start with a colon

Tags: c#, regex

I need to distinguish variable names and non variable names in some expressions I am trying to parse. Variable names start with a colon, can have (but not begin with) numbers, and have underscores. So valid variable names are:

```
:x :_x :x2 :alpha_x   // etc
```

Then I have to pick out other words in the expression that don't begin with colons. So in the following expression:

```
:result = median(:x,:y,:z)
```

The variables would be :result, :x, :y, and :z while the other non-variable word would be median.

My regex to pick out the variable names is (this works):

```
:[a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the non-variable words. My regex for that is:

```
(?<!:)([a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)
```

The issue is, the match is only excluding the first character after the : like so:

[image]

Comment: Is it true then that you need a non a-z before your non-variable word?  So `: this` should match `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?<!:)([a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)` regex still matches partial variable words because `(?<!:)` assures there is no `:` immediately to the left of the current location, and then matches an identifier without checking for a word boundary. So, in `:alpha`, `lpha` is matched because `l` is preceded with a char other than `:`.

Hence the problem is easy to solve by adding a word boundary before `[a-zA-Z_]`:

```
var words = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!:)\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%3a%29%5cb%5ba-zA-Z_%5d%5cw*%5cb&i=%3ax+%3a_x+%3ax2+%3aalpha_x+%3aresult+%3d+median%28%3ax%2c%3ay%2c%3az%29&o=e). Note you do not need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!:)` - make sure there is no `:` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\b` - a word boundary: make sure there are no letters, digits or `_` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[a-zA-Z_]` - match an ASCII letter or `_`
- `\w*` - 0+ ASCII letters, digits or `_` (**must be used with the `ECMAScript` option** to only match ASCII letters and digits and make word boundary handle ASCII only)

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern seems to work:

```
(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9_:])[a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

The lookbehind `(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9_:])` asserts that what precedes is neither a character allowed in the variable name or a colon.  This would then mark the start of a non variable word.

### Demo